# Get specific value with .filter of data

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with the text data:

```js
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Nombre":"DÓLAR B.NACIÓN",
      "VariacionPorcentual":3.63636,
      "Compra":52,
      "Venta":57,
      "UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z",
      "Orden":1
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Nombre":"DÓLAR BLUE",
      "VariacionPorcentual":19.40298,
      "Compra":53,
      "Venta":56,
      "UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z",
      "Orden":2
   }
]
```

I want only the data shown where `Id` equals 1. I know I should use `.filter()` but I don't know how implement it in my code. This `Id` should filter the value for field of bna.compra, bna.venta, etc.

```
function getBNA(callback){
  request("URL", function(err, response, body){
         if (err)
        {
          console.log("Error getting information from Lanacion", err);
          return
        }
        var bna = JSON.parse(body);
        callback(bna);
  });
}

app.all(`/${process.env.BOT_ENDPOINT}`, function(req, res){

  var cotizaciones = cotizaciones.filter(id => id===1);
  getVariacion((dolar) => getBNA((bna) => {
    var status = `️ ${dolar.fecha}
Informal:
Compra: $${dolar.compra} | Venta: $${dolar.venta}
Variación: ${dolar["class-variacion"]!=='up' ? "" : ""} ${dolar.variacion}

BNA: 
Compra: $${bna.compra} | Venta: $${bna.venta}
Variación: ${(bna.VariacionPorcentual)==0 ? "➖" : (bna.VariacionPorcentual)<0 ? "" : ""} ${(bna.VariacionPorcentual)}%`;
```

For example, I need to get:

```
️ 12/09/2019 - 10:30
Informal:
Compra: $51,88 | Venta: $54,08
Variación: 16,18%
```

Here are the values for Id:1

```
 BNA: 
Compra: $52(compra)  | Venta: $57 (venta)
Variación:  3.63636 (variacion porcentual)
```

Answer (score 4):

> I know I should use .filter()...

Not if you just want to find a single item. For that, you use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var cotizacion = cotizaciones.find(({Id}) => Id === 1);
```

Live Example:

```js
const cotizaciones = [{"Id":1,"Nombre":"DÓLAR B. NACIÓN","VariacionPorcentual":3.63636,"Compra":52,"Venta":57,"UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z","Orden":1},{"Id":2,"Nombre":"DÓLAR BLUE","VariacionPorcentual":19.40298,"Compra":53,"Venta":56,"UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z","Orden":2}];
var cotizacion = cotizaciones.find(entry => entry.Id === 1);
console.log(cotizacion.VariacionPorcentual, cotizacion.Compra, cotizacion.Venta, cotizacion.UltimaActualizacion);
```

Notice that I used destructuring in the parameter list to pick the `id` property from the object. Without destructuring:

```
var cotizacion = cotizaciones.find(entry => entry.Id === 1);
```

Live Example:

```js
const cotizaciones = [{"Id":1,"Nombre":"DÓLAR B. NACIÓN","VariacionPorcentual":3.63636,"Compra":52,"Venta":57,"UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z","Orden":1},{"Id":2,"Nombre":"DÓLAR BLUE","VariacionPorcentual":19.40298,"Compra":53,"Venta":56,"UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z","Orden":2}];
var cotizacion = cotizaciones.find(entry => entry.Id === 1);
console.log(cotizacion.VariacionPorcentual, cotizacion.Compra, cotizacion.Venta, cotizacion.UltimaActualizacion);
```

---

FWIW, I strongly recommend moving from `var` to `let` and `const`. :-)

Comment: Nice with the destructuring!! Did not know you could also do this inside arr opperators :)

Comment: Nope, I need to find from the Id:1 the value of VariacionPorcentual, Compra, Venta and UltimaActualizacion. And in base of my code, the definition that you posted it, I should define for each value whitin the getBNA((bna) => {
??

Comment: @facutopa - Right. The `cotizacion` variable will refer to the object in the array that has those properties.

Comment: if you store the unique keys in a Set then you can just say:   `.filter(row => mySet.has(row.Id) );`

Comment: @facutopa - I've added live examples. Also, I had `id` but your property is called `Id`, so I fixed that.

Comment: i just edit my code but I can't get it.

`getVariacion((dolar) => getBNA((bna) => {
    var cotizacion = bna.find(entry => entry.Id === 1);
    var status = ️ ${dolar.fecha}
Informal:
Compra: $${dolar.compra} | Venta: $${dolar.venta}
Variación: ${dolar["class-variacion"]!=='up' ? "" : ""} ${dolar.variacion}

BNA: 
Compra: $${cotizacion.compra} | Venta: $${cotizacion.venta}
Variación: ${(cotizacion.VariacionPorcentual)==0 ? "➖" : (cotizacion.VariacionPorcentual)<0 ? "" : ""} ${(cotizacion.VariacionPorcentual)}%;`  

I'm bad, I know, but I can't see in what.

Comment: @facutopa - That code has all kinds of invalid tokens in it (see the box just after `var status =`, for instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the text after `var status =` is a text that will be showed in a tweet. And each field will show the value recollected from a specific web.

Comment: @facutopa - Look at the code in the comment above. It has `️` characters in several places **outside** quotes. That makes it invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh sorry, ignore the outside of quotes, I can't post it here andd combine it with the quotes of stackoverflow. The quotes are rigth in my code. My doubt is with find, is correct implemented?

Comment: @facutopa - Yes, assuming `bna` has the structure you said `cotizaciones` did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have an Array to filter.

cotizaciones is no array from what I can see in your example code.

So first assign the array values to cotizaciones.

Once cotizaciones is an Array you implement the filter like this: 
cotizaciones.filter(arrValue => arrValue.id === 1);

the arrValue is just a name, can be anything. But I thought this was clear ;)

You can also use cotizaciones.find(arrValue => arrValue.id === 1);

If you only need to find one object out of the array, that is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

First if you have a list of keys you want to compare against for ID, you need a set:

```
const mySet = new Set(['a','b','c'])
```

then you need to filter your data.

```
const rows = [.....];
const result = rows.filter( row => mySet.has(row.Id))
```

where ID is the key being looked at.

It will make the runtime be O(n+m) where n is the conversion/generation of the set, and m is the walking of your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `filter()` method will be useful if you will be expecting a dataset with multiple objects/entries having the same "Id". Plus, it is quite simple to implement. Here you have it.

```js
function filterData(data, id) {
    return data.filter(item => item["Id"] === id);
}

var data = [{"Id":1,"Nombre":"DÓLAR B. NACIÓN","VariacionPorcentual":3.63636,"Compra":52,"Venta":57,"UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z","Orden":1},{"Id":2,"Nombre":"DÓLAR BLUE","VariacionPorcentual":19.40298,"Compra":53,"Venta":56,"UltimaActualizacion":"2019-08-13T10:32:02.810Z","Orden":2}];

console.log(filterData(data, 1));
```